# missing right parenthesis Oracle while creating table

Tags: oracle

oracle error

```
SQL> desc user_details;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------

 USER_ID                                            NUMBER(38)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(20)
 DOB                                                DATE
 CONTACT                                            NUMBER(38)
 EMAIL                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
 TYPE                                               VARCHAR2(4)


    create table user_reg
    (
    reg_id int primary key,
    pass varchar(50),
    email varchar(20) foreign key preferences user_details(user_id)
    );
```

this is what error i got while creating table user_reg

Answer (score 0):

Oracle prints error code as well as number of line with faulty statement. In your case:

```
Error at Command Line : 5 Column : 23
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Correct statement:

```
create table user_reg
(
reg_id int primary key,
pass varchar(50),
email varchar(20) references user_details(user_id)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you post the complete error message as well?

I can only see that you missspelled "**references**":

```
create table user_reg
(
reg_id int primary key,
pass varchar(50),
email varchar(20) foreign key references user_details(user_id)
);
```